# how to draw a line between dynamically added text-views?

Tags: android, textview

i have a layout which is used to add dynamic text-views.
in my layout also their is an edit text what ever text user write in edit text it will shows in dynamically generated text-views.
now i have shown that text in text views.
But i want to draw line in between every text views generated.
Like Below

Text View 1

---

Text View 2

---

Text View 3

---

i am able to do underline of each text views.
But i want output like above.

how can i do this?

thanks.

Comment: While adding a TextView add a View(line) to the bottom the TextView

Comment: i am generating text views dynamically not from Xml.

Comment: Ya..while adding your TextView and another view of height 1dp below the TextView

Comment: ListView do it automatically

Comment: i have write view in my xml but it draws only single line before textviews are added.<View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple you need to create an another two view
1. textview and 2. View
For the view you need to set an background drawable as line image.

```
Textview tv_text = new TextView(this);
View view_line =  new View(this);
tv_text.setText("Text");
View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_toggle);
Pref_Layout.addView(tv_text);
Pref_Layout.addView(view_line);
```

Hope It will work. If you still facing problem. Add it on comment, I will check it again.